# Why enthalpy change equals to heat transfer

Tags: thermodynamics

I know that at constant pressure, and when all work is external work, we can write

$$ \mathrm{d}H= q - p \,\mathrm{d}V + p \,\mathrm{d}V \tag{1} $$

and the two last expressions cancel out. But here, I matter that $p$ in the first of these expressions is the *external* pressure, and $p$ in the second one is the *internal* pressure. Considering that, we can't cancel out those terms, because we didn't make any consideration that internal and external pressures must be equal.

I know that I'm wrong, but where?

Comment: Who says the external- and internal pressures are not equaL?  Also, your first equation should read dH=dq+Vdp.

Comment: H =E+PV =  Q-W+PV; at constant pressure work is usually PdeltaV  so H=Q if only work is PV work.

Answer (score 1):

As already explained briefly by the comments under your question:

Let us recall the functional form of $H$:

$$
H=U+pV
$$

Where p is the external pressure on the system. In equilibrium, we get:

$$
dU=\delta q -pdV
$$
$$
dH=dU+pdV+VdP =\delta q-pdV+pdV+VdP = \delta q +Vdp
$$
And, at constant external pressure:
$$
dH=\left(\delta_q\right)_p
$$
Please, remember that in equilibrium external pressure should be equal to the internal pressure of the system, anyway, but not necessarly constant.

Comment: Thanks, so the enthalpy describes only equilibrium processes, reversible?

Comment: In general, all of classical thermodynamics in the formulation used by chemists mostly deals with equilibrium processes. In this particular case, it is an equilibrium process and enthalpy correctly encodes all of the information relative to the heat transfer. Anyway keep in mind that in every situation in which is possible to define the state variables, it is still possible to use enthalpy as a state function, it is just not possible to state that it is equal to the heat exchanged in the process.